# How an invalid date format can be converted to valid datetime in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

From API I am getting an datetime which is in invalid format. So how can I convert this invalid date to valid date format.

```
new Date('02-11-2021 07:11 PM')
```

Can anyone help me how to solve the problem

Comment: `Date.parse(string)` is used by `new Date(string)` under the hood.

Comment: It's not working Firefox browser.

Comment: If you read the answers to the linked question, you'll see that it will never work with that format, across browsers.

Comment: The API returns data in this format. Now I need to bind this date in UI. How can I fix this?

Comment: Parse it manually, a library can help but a parse function is maybe 4 lines of code. The highest ranked answer in the duplicate shows how to do it.